# Mongoose access multiple collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In mongodb I have one collection named as People.
It contains:

```
_id:Number,
name:String,
friends:[{friendsId:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'People'},addedTime: Date}]
```

I want to search a name of friend of a particular user and return the _id of that friend in a single query using mongoose in node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its impossible to retrieve the data in a single query/populate. Since mongodb is not a relational database. Iterate the data separately & give the result as callback to next query.